# Проблема в Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Существует следующий блок: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И всё казалось бы хорошо, но заключив  блок с изображениями товаров в `<div>` мы получаем следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем это связано и как это можно исправить?

Разметка:

```
        <div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img src="img/production/napoleon.png" alt="">
                <p>НАПОЛЕОН</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img src="img/production/choco.png" alt="">
                <p>ШОКОЛАДНЫЙ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img src="img/production/medovik.png" alt="">
                <p>МЕДОВИК</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: потому что обёртка в данном случае требует класса row

Comment: Жуть, а почему в 3-м бутстрапе такого не было?

Comment: ну, там строго говоря, тоже row требовался, просто 3-й бутстрап на float'ах - там обёртка не столь критична, а 4-й на флексах - тут без обёртки никуда

Answer (score 0):

Допишите `div` два класса `row` и `d-flex`, или используйте код который написан ниже:

```css
.wrapp {
  display: flex;
}

.img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #000;
}

.col-lg-4 {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <p>НАПОЛЕОН</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <p>ШОКОЛАДНЫЙ</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <p>МЕДОВИК</p>
  </div>
</div>
```